# "Nowadays" versus "now days"

Tags: word-choice, etymology, spacing

Recently, I was auto-corrected by a word processor when I typed in "now days" to "nowadays." Why did it do this to me? "Nowadays" looks and sounds silly, incorrect, and made-up to me.

Which version is appropriate? Which is most appropriate? Where did the word "nowadays" even come from?

Comment: You can look it up. As for why word processors do what they do: they're cursed. Don't use them. End of the world predicted: film at eleven.

Comment: What does *now days* mean? [Nowadays](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nowadays?q=nowadays).

Comment: I suppose someone **did** make this up... sometime in the [14th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nowadays&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: @MετάEd: didn't you hear? Film cancelled, due to unforeseen apocalypse.

Comment: @MattЭллен I'm assuming now days means what it does in context like: I waited, but now days have passed and I'm not seeing any progress. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nowadays%2Ccurrently%2Cpresently%2Cpresent+day%2C+these+days&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnowadays%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurrently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpresently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpresent%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20days%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nowadays, the word is *nowadays*. You can find it [in any dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=nowadays&ls=a) (unlike [*now days*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=now+days&ls=a)). The better ones will also have the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=nowadays&searchmode=none):

> late 14c., contracted from Middle English *nou adayes* (mid-14c.), from *now* + *adayes* "during the day," with adverbial genitive (see *day*).

As you can see, it *used* to be two words — *seven centuries* ago.

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) does have a few cites for *now days*, but frankly, just look at the figures yourself:

```
 nowadays    3167
 now days       7
```

And here are the figures from the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
 nowadays    1556
 now days       0
```

That's how tiny a minority you're in. For once, the spellchecker is actually right.

Comment: This is a good analysis. It looks like hardly anyone uses two words now days.